# Query non-date specific data in date specific table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data set that is not date specific, but I want to return through SQL the data aligned with a start date.

Here is an example of my data

```
Project   mon1  mon2  mon3  mon4
-------   ---   ---   ---   ---
Test1     .15   .20   .10   1.5
Test2     .50   .35   .25   .15
```

And I want to return based another table showing start dates

```
Project   Start
-------   -----
Test1     May
Test2     April
```

So the result of the query would look like this.

```
Project  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
-------  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
Test1                        .15  .20  .10  1.5
Test2                   .50  .35  .25  .15
```

Any thoughts on how to structure the SQL?

Comment: A project can start in any month and the duration may take it into the next year.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `iif()`, but it is painful.  Here is an example:

```
select d.project,
       iif(start = 'Jan' then mon1, iif(start = 'Dec', mon2, iif(start = 'Nov', mon3, iif(start = 'Oct', mon4, NULL)))) as Jan,
       iif(start = 'Feb' then mon1, iif(start = 'Jan', mon2, iif(start = 'Dec', mon3, iif(start = 'Nov', mon4, NULL)))) as Feb,
       . . . 
from data as d join
     othertable as t
     on d.project = t.project;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm going to suggest only works in RDBM's that support some form of a modulus operation/function, and it's a real stretch at that.

First off, you need to create a table that has each month's name/value, something like this:

```
MonthNbr   MonthName
---------- -----------
1          January
2          February
3          March
4          April
5          May
6          June
7          July
8          August
9          September
10         October
11         November
12         December
```

And then you need to join the tables together, figure out which month goes where, display, something like this:

```
SELECT
   proj.Project,
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 0, 12) == 1) data.mon1 "Jan",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 1, 12) == 2) data.mon2 "Feb",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 2, 12) == 3) data.mon3 "Mar",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 3, 12) == 4) data.mon4 "Apr",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 4, 12) == 5) data.mon5 "May",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 5, 12) == 6) data.mon6 "Jun",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 6, 12) == 7) data.mon7 "Jul",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 7, 12) == 8) data.mon8 "Aug",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 8, 12) == 9) data.mon9 "Sep",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 9, 12) == 10) data.mon10 "Oct",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 10, 12) == 11) data.mon11 "Nov",
   if (MOD(mnth.MonthNbr + 11, 12) == 12) data.mon12 "Dec"
FROM
   project_table proj
       JOIN months_table mnth ON (proj.Start = mnth.MonthName)
       JOIN data_type data ON (proj.Project = data.Project)
```

The exact syntax is to whatever database you're implementing and I'm not convinced this works when it rolls over (data.mon4 actually should be in January because of whatever the start number is).  You might also need to translate mon1/mon2/etc into numbers and then have a massive DECODE for each column to get the right value.

Really, a stored procedure/TransactSQL/whatever-procedure-language-it-supports) is more appropriate, to write all the necessary logic in the SQL itself might not even be possible.